# insert-update pdo mysql query and get last inserted id, if needed

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert-update

I have simple insert/update page where I do check if there is "id", if no then proceed insert query otherwise proceed update query,  and this works fine. Problem is that I need that id for the next query, in case of Insert query I will get it as "lastInsertId" but in case of Update query "lastInsertId" will overwrite $_POST["id"].

Is there a way to identify which query has been performed (insert or update) and then get right id, or I have to bind/ execute query's separately?

```
$id= $_POST["id"];  
  try { 
    $DBH = db_connect ();
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
      if ($id== "") {
         $query= $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO table (x1,x2) VALUES(:x1,:x2)');                        
      } else {
         $query= $DBH->prepare('UPDATE day SET x1=:x1, x2=:x2 WHERE id= :id'); 
           $query-> bindValue(':id', $id);
      }

           $query-> bindValue(':x1', $x1);
           $query-> bindValue(':x2', $x2);                                                                  
           $query-> execute();                              

        $id= $DBH-> lastInsertId('id') ; //get last inserted ID
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exactly the same if clause as for picking the insert query as the query to excecute. Then your code would look like this:

```
$id= $_POST["id"];  
    try { 
      $DBH = db_connect ();
      $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
      if ($id== "") {
         $query= $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO table (x1,x2)     VALUES(:x1,:x2)');
      } else {
         $query= $DBH->prepare('UPDATE day SET x1=:x1, x2=:x2 WHERE id= :id'); 
         $query-> bindValue(':id', $id);
      }

       $query-> bindValue(':x1', $x1);
       $query->bindValue(':x2',$x2);                                                                  
       $query-> execute();

    if($id==""){
        $id= $DBH-> lastInsertId('id') ; //get last inserted ID
    }
}
```